# Why cant i read and write to this file without overwriting it?

Tags: c++

I have a function that reads from a file and overwrites the file with some new data.
The variables filename_in and filename_out refer to the same file.

Here is the code

```
void decrypt(const aes_key_t& key, const aes_iv_t& iv,
    const std::string& filename_in, const std::string& filename_out) {
    CryptoPP::CFB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption cipher{};
    cipher.SetKeyWithIV(key.data(), key.size(), iv.data());

    std::ifstream in{ filename_in, std::ios::binary };
    std::ofstream out{ filename_out, std::ios::binary};

    CryptoPP::FileSource{ in, /*pumpAll=*/true,
                         new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter{
                             cipher, new CryptoPP::FileSink{out}} };
}
```

I am trying to read and write to that file but I end up with an empty file when the function executes. I don't want to append to the file, I intend to overwrite it but all I get is an empty file

Comment: I don't understand. You want to overwrite the file (meaning get rid of the old content so you can add new content) without losing the old content? Isn't that logically impossible? Or were you thinking that any contents beyond what you wrote would be kept (something I might describe as overwriting the contents, rather than overwriting the file)? Maybe you need to take more than a few sentences to explain what you mean. Maybe add an example to help explain.

Comment: I phrased my question wrongly but i fixed the  issue. Thanks

Comment: *"but i fixed the issue"* -- you mean you fixed *your* issue. And now you have absolutely no interest in helping the next person with the same problem? This site is supposed to be a library of questions and answers to help people in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This is how your operating system works. A file that's opened for writing has its existing contents erased immediately, when it opens. In your program that happens before its existing contents get read.

The most common way of dealing with this is to write the output to a different file. Then after both files get closed the new file is renamed to the same filename as the existing file.